# recieveing Promise { <pending> } error nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, e-commerce, payment

i have created an ecommerce app from scratch using nodejs and have implemented payments using stripe... i have the code below, but it not rendering stripe checkout page and is logging  Promise { pending } in the console. has anyone had this error before?

```
 app.post('/create-checkout-session', (req, res) => {

  var amount = stringify(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.sessionID)
  var userId = req.body.sessionID
  console.log("email: " + req.body.customer_email)
  var email = req.body.customer_email;
  var deliveryTotal = req.body.totalWithDelivery;
  var totalVal = amount.split("=");
  var totalPrice = parseFloat(totalVal[1]);
  //console.log("TOTAL PRICE: " + totalPrice);
  var finalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100);

  var finalTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100) + parseFloat(Math.round(deliveryTotal));
  console.log("final total: " + finalTotal);
  var itemName = ""
  var itemPrice = ""
  var totalNewPriceTest = ""
  //query to database

  var productsStripe = "select * from " + userId
  console.log(userId)
  console.log("query to db for displaying cart on stripe page")
  ibmdb.open("DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID="";PWD="";", function (err,conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(productsStripe, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(rows)
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        itemName = rows[i]['ITEM']
        itemPrice = rows[i]['PRICE']
        totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(rows[i]['PRICE'])
        console.log("item name : " + itemName + " " + itemPrice )
        totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest);
        console.log("final overall prcie: " + (totalNewPriceTest))
      }
      console.log("inside productsStripe function.")
      console.log("overall prcie: " + totalNewPriceTest)

      totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest)


      var grandTotal = totalNewPriceTest;
      var finalGrandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal)
      console.log(parseFloat(finalGrandTotal))



      // continue executing here    
      //stripe
      const session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ['CA'],
        },

        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: 'CAD',
              product_data: {
                name: itemName,
              },
              unit_amount: finalGrandTotal,
              //finalTotal * 100
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],

        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'localhost:1001/successPg',
        cancel_url: 'localhost:1001/catalogue',
        customer_email: email,
      });
      console.log(session)
      res.json({ id: session.id });
      //console.log("customer id" + customer.id)
      console.log("totalNewPriceTest " + totalNewPriceTest)

    })
  })
});
```

if anyone has any clue as to what could be going on, please let me know what I can do to figure this out. I know it may have something to do with async, nodejs has an interesting way of doing async functions.

Comment: what is the error? `Promise <pending>` isn't an error, that's the state of a Promise - which line of code is outputing this *error* - I predict that it's `console.log(session)` - since it's most likely that `stripe.checkout.sessions.create` returns a Promise

Comment: simple fix ... add `async` as shown - `conn.query(productsStripe, async function (err, rows) {` - then `const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({`

Comment: that worked, thank you!